# PHP can't reach url

Tags: php, linux, magento, networking, soap

Today I set up some new PCs with Linux Mint and wanted to get my Magento-SOAP API run locally.
If I run the script:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magento.dev/mageapi/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('login' => 'apiuser', 'password' => '12345678', 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'trace'=>1))
```

I get an error that it can't reach http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
So I tried it with:

```
php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/');" -d allow_url_fopen=1
```

If I tun it trough the local network I get the warning:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/):   
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in Command line code on line 1
```

But If I run it through my mobile phone (via tethering) it works just fine.

It does not look like a network, but more like a local DNS-issue. On my MacBook and on my Windows device in the same network it's running fine.

Comment: Do you have an active internet connection? "cant reach: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" is thrown usually when there is no internet

Comment: Yes I do have an active internet connection. I can reach  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" from web browser too.